# Python: Determine co-ordinates of a point after rotation in OpenCV using warpPerspective

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have an image `img2` with two certain co-ordinates `point1(x,y)` and `point2(x,y)`. When I rotate the image with an angle `anglediff` these points shift to new location in new image `rotated_image2`, which I want to determine using `cv2.warpPerspective`. For this I supply these points as a numpy array `pts` to the function.

```
  pts = np.array([[point1[0],point1[1]],[point2[0],point2[0]]]) #given points
  M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts,rotated_image2)
  dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img2,M,(500,400))
```

**Problem:**
While running the function, script throws

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-zeowd5_m/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3391: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 in function 'getPerspectiveTransform'
```

which after my research points to the fact that either of those variables `pts` or `rotated_image_2` is not passed correctly.

**Question:**

1. How do I go about finding the new co-ordinates of P1 and P2 in the new rotated image?
2. If I am on the right way, how do I go about solving this issue?

Comment: probably wrong data format. Looks like `warpPerspective` is expecting `float32` while you pass `float64`?

Comment: converting datatype with `dtype="float32"` made no difference.

Comment: and please note, the error is being thrown by   `M=cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts,rotated_image2)`

Answer (score -2):

`getPerspectiveTransform` expects four points in the first argument (`src`) and four points in the second argument (`dst`). you are passing two points for the first, and an unknown variable in the second argument.

`src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4` checks whether the input is CV_32F (single float) and whether it is 2 columns, 4 rows.

in any case, once you have the homography, you can pass it to warpPerspective to warp a picture, or to `perspectiveTransform` to transform an array of points/coordinates.

invert the homography matrix (`np.linalg.inv` or OpenCV's own APIs) to map things the other way.